# C++ Friend Functions Improve Encapsulation?

Tags: c++, friend

There are a number of posts about the C++ friend keyword. I see the advantages of having friend classes. Many concerns are raised and answered regarding whether or not encapsulation is broken by the friend keyword, but all of these responses seem to be directed towards using friend for classes.

But what about friend functions? I can't for the life of me see why you would want this. Once you have any friend function, aren't you allowing any class that ever comes along to access all your private data/functions?

```
class Foo
{
private:
    int neverSetToZero;
public:
    Foo() { neverSetToZero = 1; }

    friend void Whateveryoudowiththisdonttouchneversettozero(Foo * t);
};

void Whateveryoudowiththisdonttouchneversettozero(Foo * t)
{
    (*t).neverSetToZero=0;
}

int main()
{
    Foo t;
    Whateveryoudowiththisdonttouchneversettozero(&t);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the question? If your specific code breaks encapsulation or if there is a general use for friend functions?

Comment: Since the friends must be declared in the class definition, they don't break encapsulation any more than member functions do. They're just part of the class interface, allowing more flexible calling patterns than you can get from member functions.

Comment: What are you asking? In your example fiend function is basically the same as public method with `this` moved to arguments. "C-style".

Comment: Since I haven't ever coded with others, maybe my conceptual understanding is off...but the way I understand it is I need to be concerned about other people misusing my classes...that's the real point behind having private data and functions. Is this wrong? If I'm correct, then having a friend function seems to allow this in an uncontrolled manner.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Where did I have to declare who the friend is that can use the function? By declaring a friend function, it seems to allow anyone to come along and define that function...

Comment: @David but it is YOU who implement this function, not the user. Your user code is in `main()`

Comment: @Drop Thanks...that's what I don't see.  If I have class A with a friend function, can't you come along with a new file and define that function? It seems like that's what my code above does.

Comment: @David: No, as with any function, there can be only one definition. It can't be redefined any more than a member function can. The class implementor has exactly the same control over that function's implementation as they do over the member functions.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Oh I see...so if I leave it undefined, then that is where the problem comes up. If I define it, then no one can redefine it later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say that a friend function is simply an extension of the public interface of the class, which uses a slightly different syntax and allows implicit conversions on all of its parameters (whereas member functions don't do that on their first/implied parameter).

In other words, the author of the class which grants friendship should be the one in control of the friend function. If you just declare a friend function in your class and allow clients to define that function, then certainly hell breaks loose (and program breaks down). But that's not what friend functions are for.

Answer (score 4):

> But what about friend functions? I can't for the life of me see why you would want this.

The common use case for adding a `friend` function is to place implementation logic into a function that cannot be a member function, but must be a free-standing function instead.

For example, non-member binary operators and overloads of the `<<` operator are commonly made friends of the corresponding classes.

In all cases of a `friend` function that I have seen, the code that "friends" a function also supplies the implementation of the same function. There is no use case for leaving an unimplemented friend function in your class. Essentially, the feature lets you build free-standing logic with the knowledge of your class.